# Release mode of qmake is always building in debug mode

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

```
qmake.exe unittests.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2010 "CONFIG+=CodeCoverage"
jom.exe -f Makefile.release
```

My unittests.pro:

```
# unit test linkage
ROOT=$$PWD/../../..
APPS=$$ROOT/apps
EXTERNAL=$$ROOT/external

CUTE_TEST_DIR = $$EXTERNAL/cutetest

debug_and_release {
CONFIG -= debug_and_release
CONFIG += debug_and_release
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
CONFIG -= debug release
CONFIG += debug
}
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
CONFIG -= debug release
CONFIG += release
}

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = UnitTestSuite
DESTDIR = ./bin
MOC_DIR = release/.moc
OBJECTS_DIR = ./obj
UI_DIR = ./ui
RCC_DIR = ./rcc
```

When I ran these build steps from my Qt Creator 5.2.1 I get my unit test application built with debug version alsways, I mean it is calling the my real application UI in debug mode instead of my test application.
I think the qmake is always forcing to build my test application in debug mode.

Could someone suggest the is there any problem with the qmake in 5.2.1 opensource or I have to add arguments to fix this.

Thanks

NK

Comment: Try adding also `CONFIG-=debug_and_release`. Also check that there's no CONFIG += debug etc hardcoded in any of your .pro files (for the unit test, in particular)

Comment: When you built Qt, did you configure for debug only? Is this the only application that only builds a debug version, or is it a more general problem?

Comment: @ Frank Osterfeld

Thanks for the reply.
I tried the config that you have mentioned, the problem that I see in my unittestsuite app is intermittent and when I compared the Makefile.Release for the working and not working case it is almost different in the call sequence of the project files and the obj files are differen too.

Comment: @ rainbowgoblin

Thanks for the reply.
I am using the same qmake for building my real application it is working fine and I even tried with the QtCreator5.2.1/bin/qmake but still the unittestsuite app is building in debug mode.

Note: This issue I am seeing intermittently after the clean build or checking out the code everytime.

Comment: Thanks.
the issue was with my config for debug and release.
It got resolved.

Comment: Answer your questions with how you fixed it please...